# функция, которая принимает имя файла и находит количество строк, превышающее 6 символов

Tags: python, файловая-система

стоит задача:

> Напишите функцию find_lines_len_more_6, которая принимает имя файла и
> находит количество строк, превышающее 6 символов. Не забывайте
> исключать знак переноса на новую строку, стоящий в конце строки.
>
> Функция find_lines_len_more_6 должна возвращать найденное количество
> строк

подскажите пожалуйста где и в чем ошибка в написанном мной коде:

```
def find_lines_len_more_6(file_name:str) -> int:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        file_name = file_name.split('\n')
        return sum(1 for line in file_name if len(line)>6)+1
```

пробовала убирать +1 в возвращаемом значении, код все равно не проходит на решение

Comment: Подскажите, каким образом выполняется данное условие в вашем коде? **Не забывайте исключать знак переноса на новую строку**

Comment: "принимает имя файла и находит количество строк"  очевидно имеется ввиду количество строк в самом файле ? если это так ,  я бы заменил
file_name = file_name.split('\n')  на
file_name = f.read().splitlines()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибок в вашем коде две:

1. `file_name = file_name.split('\n')` - после открытия файла на чтение вы не читаете содержимое файла при помощи функции `read()`, а начинаете парсить его название
2. `sum(1 for line in file_name if len(line)>6)+1` - +1 в конце совершенно ни к чему.

Если исправить, то получается рабочий код:

```
def find_lines_len_more_6(file_name: str) -> int:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        return sum(1 for line in lines if len(line) > 6)


print(find_lines_len_more_6('test.txt')) # 2
```

test.txt

```
123456
1234567
12345
12345678
```

Как верно написали в комментариях для разбития файла на строки лучше использовать функцию `str.splitlines()`, поскольку для разделения в ней используется не только символ переноса строки `\n`, но и другие.